# How to put the correct year in the date with python?

Tags: python

How can I put the current year to a column of dates in a DataFrame.
I have this code that changes the format of a date but I am putting an incorrect year and I want to put the current year, does anyone know how I can do it, thanks in advance.

```
importpandas as pd
date['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(date['Fecha'], format='%m/%d')
```

[Result delivered to me:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyJrW.png)

[Result I want:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxSmJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import pandas as pd
date['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(date['Fecha']+"/2022", format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the 'correct' year is 2022, you can use

```
date['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime("2022/" + date['Fecha'], format='%Y/%m/%d')
```

If you want to update it every year with the current year, you can do:

```
from datetime import date
pd.to_datetime(str(date.today().year) + date['Fecha'], format='%Y%m/%d')
```